# Does attribute specifier sequence inherit?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, language-lawyer, c++17

Look at this snippet:

```
struct [[nodiscard]] Result {
};


struct DiscardableResult: Result {
};
```

Does `DiscardableResult` have the `[[nodiscard]]` attribute? If yes, is it possible to remove it somehow?

Comment: The standard doesn't state that attributes are inherited, so I believe we should assume that attributes are not inherited in general. The standard also doesn't state that `nodiscard` is inherited.

Comment: both gcc and clang with `-std-c++1z` seem to not inherit the attribute.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[dcl.attr.nodiscard]/2 says:

> A `nodiscard` call is a function call expression that calls a function previously declared `nodiscard`, or whose return type is a possibly cv-qualified class or enumeration type marked `nodiscard`.

The return type of the function is `DiscardableResult`. This type is not marked `nodiscard`, as defined in [dcl.attr.grammar]/5:

> Each attribute-specifier-seq is said to appertain to some entity or statement, identified by the **syntactic context where it appears** (Clause 9, Clause 10, Clause 11). If an attribute-specifier-seq that appertains to some entity or statement contains an attribute or alignment-specifier that is not allowed to apply to that entity or statement, the program is ill-formed. If an attribute-specifier-seq appertains to a friend declaration (14.3), that declaration shall be a definition. No attribute-specifier-seq shall appertain to an explicit instantiation (17.7.2).

Emphasis added.

There is no attribute in the "syntactic context" of `DiscardableResult`. Therefore, no attribute "appertains" to this entity.

Attributes are not inherited.